# Convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{h(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$, where $h(x)$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does the improper integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{h(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx,$$

where $h(x)$ is continuous, converge?

My attempt:

take $g(x) = 1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$. So, $\lim_{x\to 1} f/g = h(1) $. since $h(1)\in \mathbb R$, integration $g$ on $0$ to $1$ converges implies integration $f$ on $0$ to $1$ converges.

Now,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 g(x)dx &= \lim _{c \to 1}\int_0^c \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\\\
&= \lim_{ c \to 1} \arcsin(c)\\\\
&= \pi/2.
\end{align}

So integration $g$ converges on $0$ to $1$ implies integration $f$ converges on $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Please use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: I (half) fixed your mathjax formatting. But what is f?

Comment: f is the first function that's h(x)/√(1-x^2)

Comment: $\Big|\frac{h(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\Big|\leq \|h\|_u\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ in integrable (as improper integral) ober $(0,1)$ the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac1{1=x^2}$ diverges.  So, $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{h(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ne h(1)$. Rather, it also diverges.  So unfortunately, your way forward won't work.

---

If $h(x)=0$, then the result is trivial.  We assume, therefore, that $h(x)$ is not identically $0$.

Proceeding, we use the Cauchy Criterion to prove convergence.  Proceeding , let $\varepsilon >0$ be given.  Then, since $\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$ converges, there exists a number $0<\gamma(\varepsilon)<1$ such that whenever $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ belong to the interval $(\gamma,1)$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\right|&<\frac{\varepsilon}{\max_{[0,1]}|h(x)|}
\end{align}$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_{\beta_1}^{\beta_2} \frac{h(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\right|&<\frac{\varepsilon}{\max_{[0,1]}|h(x)|}\,\times \max_{[0,1]}|h(x)|=\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

And we are done!